# Extract MSBuild Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have an MSBuild file like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Param1>Hello world</Param1>
  </PropertyGroup>      
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Param1>Goodbye world</Param1>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am working on an external application and I need to be able to find out what  the configured value of Param1 is. I need a way to correctly evaluate the MSBuild file so that any conditions are applied and then the correct parameter returned to the calling application.

Being able to do something like this would be great:

```
>MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release MyBuild.proj  -extractParam:Param1
>Goodbye World
```

Any ideas? Is this possible with C# instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the project output the value, then parse it using scripting/C#/....

Add this target to your project:

```
<Target Name="OutputParam1" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="Param1 = $(Param1)"/>
</Target>
```

it will be invoked automatically after the Build target.
Then on the commandline:

```
>MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release MyBuild.proj /fl
```

where /fl cause the file msbuild.log to be generated, which will contain amongst others a line

```
Param1 = Goodbye world
```

because of the Message task. Now use e.g. powershell to output the matching part:

```
>powershell -command "$a = Select-String -Path msbuild.log -Pattern 'Param1 = (.+)'; $a.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value"
>Goodbye world
```

Comment: You could run this target in particular too: MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release /t:OutputParam1 MyBuild.proj . Also, if this property's value depends on Build, then use DependsOnTargets="Build"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a target which prints the param value:

```
<Target Name="ExtractParam1" >
  <Message Text="$(Param1)" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

The switches `/v:m /nologo` makes the output print just the value:

> msbuild /p:Configuration=Release MyBuild.proj /t:ExtractParam1 /v:m /nologo